# Receiving System.NotSupportedException when trying to make a string ProperCase (VB)

Tags: vba, vb.net

```
Private Sub btnNewStudent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewStudent.Click
        Dim name As String = InputBox("Enter the Student's Name", "Name", "Student Name")
        name = StrConv(name, vbProperCase)
        addStudent(name)
        If name = "" Then
            errorMessage("Please Enter a Name")
            lstStudents.Items.Remove("")
        End If
End Sub
```

**Error Description:**

> "System.NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding
> 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

**Error Details:**

> System.NotSupportedException   HResult=0x80131515   Message=No data
> is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom
> encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider
> method.   Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.StrConv(String str, VbStrConv
> Conversion, Int32 LocaleID)    at
> StudentTrackerVB.frmStudentTrackers.btnNewStudent_Click(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) in E:\College\Year 2\Unit 15 - Object Oriented
> Programming\Assignment
> 3\StudentTrackerVB\StudentTrackerVB\Form1.vb:line 11    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
> button, Int32 clicks)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg,
> IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

When I try to make name into ProperCase, it comes up with an error. I've done a similar thing for items in an array making them UpperCase which works perfectly. But for some reason, this doesn't?

What am I doing wrong xD

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or error messages. They are both text so post them as text, formatted appropriately. We can't copy and paste text from a picture if we want to execute code or search for error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Globalization

```
    Dim ti As Globalization.TextInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo
    name = ti.ToTitleCase(name)
```

[Changing Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/changing-case)

Comment: Thank you! I originally didnt know how to add globalization to a class, but I used `Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase()` for it! I'm used to C# where you can just do `Using System.Globalization` but that doesn't seem to work in VB xD Thank you again!!!

Comment: @Ash look at Imports https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type

Comment: Wow, thank you! That's perfect!! I'll give that a try! :3